# Prove posterior mean is positive if and only if signal is positive, assuming zero prior mean

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

Suppose that:

$\Delta \sim G$, where $G$ is a distribution that is symmetric about the origin

I get a normally-distributed signal:

$\hat{\delta} \: |\Delta, \tau^2 \sim N(\Delta, \tau^2)$

How can I prove that the posterior mean $E(\Delta | \hat{\delta})$ is positive if and only if the signal $\hat{\delta}$ is positive.

(Intuition: The prior mean is zero, so the posterior mean should assume the sign of the signal $\hat{\delta}$)

Comment: Perhaps you can look at comparing the likelihoods $\Lambda_{\hat \delta}(\Delta=d)$ and $\Lambda_{\hat \delta}(\Delta=-d)$.  You may need to presume that various conditional expectations are finite.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful. Note

$\hat{\delta}=\Delta+\epsilon$,

where $\epsilon$ is normally distributed with mean zero and variance $\tau^2$. Let this normal density be given by $\phi$. Note

$$P(\hat{\delta} \leq c)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{y-c} \phi(y) g(x) dxdy $$

Here $g$ is the density function of $G$ (if this does not exist you can still use more general integrals).Density is obtained via Leibniz rule

$$f(c)=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(y) g(y-c) dy $$

The conditional density is

$$f(\Delta| \hat{\delta})=\frac{\phi(\hat{\delta}-\Delta) g(\Delta)}{f(\delta)}$$

And then

$$\mathbb{E}(\Delta| \hat{\delta})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Delta f(\Delta| \hat{\delta})d\Delta$$

$\Delta \phi(\hat{\delta}-\Delta) g(\Delta)$ is symmetric around $\hat{\delta}=0$. You need to show that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Delta\phi(\hat{\delta}-\Delta) g(\Delta)d\Delta>0$$

iff $\hat{\delta}>0$

Comment: Thanks! This does seem helpfu. Will give it some thought